# Maven "Download Sources" is not available for a jar in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am using Maven2.2.1 in my environment, I am facing an issue, 
for few jars under maven dependencies directory if you right click on a jar-->maven-->Download Source(is not coming), other jars are not having this issue: i am able to see download sources in the menu. Any idea about this...pls help me?

[image: M2Eclipse Screenshot]

Thanks,
Sundar

Answer (score 1):

A) download sources is only available when you right-click the project, not a jar.

B) not every artifact has sources. View the `Maven Console` inside the `Console View` (`Window > Show View > Console`) to see which don't.

[image: Find the Maven Console]

[image: Maven Console Output]

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on whether the sources are available in the Maven repository. If there are no source JARs available then no source will be downloaded.